# How to use keep_if with string array

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use [keep_if](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-keep_if) in my Rails 5 app with Ruby 2.3.1.

```
a = ["a", "b", "c", "d" ]
b = ["b", "d"]

a.keep_if { |v| v=~ /["#{b}"]/ }
#=> ["b", "d"]
```

**Real project:**

```
a = ["apple", "banana", "orange"]
b = ["mangoes", "banana", "pear"]

a.keep_if { |v| v=~ /["#{b}"]/ }
#=> ["mangoes", "banana", "pear"]
```

**What I expected:**

```
#=> ["banana"]
```

I'm guessing some sort of regex to be used? How to get what I expected?

Comment: What about `a.keep_if { |v| b.include?(v) }`?

Comment: Egad! Why the rush to select an answer???

Comment: To understand why your code didn't work, think about what this actually does: `/["#{b}"]/`. When you use string interpolation (`#{...}`), Ruby calls `to_s` on the value and puts the result into the string. `b.to_s` in this case returns `["b", "d"]`, so your final regular expression is this: `/["["b", "d"]"]/`. Inspecting that regular expression would have been a good first step for debugging this code.

Comment: Sylar, one reason for not being too hasty in selecting an answer is that someone may come by and show that the answer with the greenie is incorrect.

Comment: I'll try out the others later and I do upvote helpful answers so why not post an answer to earn credit?

Comment: I was a bit hasty, never been that hasty before.

Comment: @Sylar: And I should've looked more into how to use `keep_if`:) Thanks @CarySwoveland.

Comment: @Jordan, thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[keep_if()](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/keep_if) deletes every element of `self` for which block evaluates to `false`. See [Array#select!](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select%21)

If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

@Cary Swoveland has mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195337/how-to-use-keep-if-with-string-array/38195395#comment63815958_38195337) that the following should work if you want to use `keep_if()`:

```
a.keep_if { |v| b.include?(v) }   #=> ["banana"]
```

The following would work if you wanted to use `Array#select!` instead for perhaps a different scenario:

```
c = a+b
c.select { |x| c.count(x) == 2 }.uniq   #=> ["banana"]
# (use .uniq > 2 for values that appear more than once)
```

Comment: All right! I really thought `keep_if` would work. Thanks.

Comment: Regarding your #2, what if `a = [1, 2, 1]` and `b = [2]`?

Comment: In your first example what is the array `b` that is transformed to your regex, and what is the transformation? If `a = ['ab', 'cd]`, neither `b = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']` nor `b = ['aeiou']` would work, as both would result in is `ab` being kept (selected) in `a`, which is incorrect.

Comment: That example shows one way `keep_if` can be used. That's all.  The OP has arrays `a` and `b`. Your answer must be in terms of those arrays.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'll remove the code block as it may be confusing to you.

Comment: It's not the least bit confusing to me. I've given a counterexample to your solution (one of many), but you've let it stand. I've therefore downvoted your answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'm happy for you to provide your own answer to the question so I myself and perhaps the OP can learn. Perhaps my answer isn't the best one? Sorry if I misunderstood your comments.

Comment: C'mon, if `a = [1, 2, 1]` and `b = [2]`, `c = a+b #=> [1, 2, 1, 2]` then `c.select { |x| c.count(x) == 2 }.uniq #=> [1, 2]`, but `1` from `a` is not to be kept (selected) because it is not an element of `b`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I see what you mean now. I've included your valid comments as part of my answer.

Comment: @CarySwoveland's method works! I'll use that one. Guess we were a bit jumpy on this one.

Comment: Did you seriously just copy and paste my comment from above into your own answer? Unless you want to mark your answer Community Wiki, that's not gonna fly. I'm not sure if I should edit your answer or downvote it or both. **Edit:** I've edited it.